# Nginx перенаправление запроса с 80 порта

Tags: linux, nginx, веб-сервер

Развернул на 80 порту nginx. При запросе http://10.38.17.33 отдает страницу nginx.
На 9200 порту у меня развернут elasticsearch, на 5601 kibana. По требованиям безопасности у меня может быть открыты только порты 80 и 443. Поэтому через nginx мне нужно перенаправлять запрос с 80 на 9200 и 5601.

Как сделать так, чтобы при запросе http://10.38.17.33/elastic запрос перенаправлялся на localhost:9200, а при http://10.38.17.33/kibana запрос перенаправлялся на localhost:5601?

Я пытался сделать Настройку Nginx как обратный прокси. Прописал в nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    location / {
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}


server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   10.38.17.23/elastic;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:9200;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
   }
```

Это не сработало, все равно перекидывает на страницу nginx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Убрать из конфига обе директивы server и написать примерно следующее:

```
upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:9200;
}
upstream kibana {
    server 127.0.0.1:5601;
}
server {
    listen        80;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    location / {
        return   200 'Hello!';
    }
    location /elastic/ {
        rewrite       /elastic/(.*)       /$1  break;
        proxy_pass    http://elastic;
    }
    location /kibana/ {
        rewrite       /kibana/(.*)       /$1  break;
        proxy_pass    http://kibana;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все заработало!